# How do I hide these lines from automatic weight bones?

Tags: rigging

[image]

So I'm making a Sonic model and I rigged the fingers with automatic weight bones, and these weird lines appeared. I'm trying to render it in OpenGL, but these lines won't disappear. Is there a way to hide them?

Answer (score 2):

N->Display->(uncheck)Relationship Lines[image]